# Location of Xorg headers on FreeBSD 10

Tags: xorg, compiling, freebsd, directory-structure

I'm running FreeBSD 10 and I'd like to build dwm. I've installed Xorg using `pkg install`. Where are the headers located? Maybe I'm just old fashioned but I first looked in `/usr/X11R6` ... not there. Anyone has any idea where Xorg will install its headers files in FreeBSD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install dwm from [port](http://www.freshports.org/x11-wm/dwm/) (/usr/ports/x11-wm/dwm). You can use own config.h:

```
make DWM_CONF=/path/to/dwm/config.h
```

I think you should use the port system instead of own compiling - it appears in your packages list.

Answer (score 4):

Same place as earlier versions. `/usr/local/include/xorg` but most of what you want is probably in `/usr/local/include/X11` from xproto and libX11...

Also `pkg info -lx xorg-server` will list files installed by xorg-server which can help point you in the right direction.